# Update route and model for MongoDB either removes data or throws an error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've searched around for a while, and I haven't come across anything quite like the problem I'm having.

I'm working on a MERN stack application with four routes. Three of the routes work fine, but my fourth route, and the model for the database, are giving me trouble.

Here is the model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let bucketListItem = new Schema({
itemOnList: { type: String, required: true },
status: { type: String, required: true },
dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
completed: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("bucketListItem", 
bucketListItem);
```

This is the JSON I've been using in Postman to test the update function (I copied it from a GET request, which is why it has an _id and __v):

```
{
"completed": true,
"_id": "5c8b05c701eb8007dceb3aaa",
"itemOnList": "Visit Venice",
"status": "btdt.",
"dateCreated": null,
"__v": 0
}
```

As you can see in the model, I have four fields, two of which I've set to 'required: true'. When I try updating any of the fields, like switching true to false or changing the status to a different message, I receive an error saying the two fields are required, even though all the fields contain information.

Here is the error message:

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": {
        "status": {
            "message": "Path `status` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `status` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "status"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "status"
        },
        "itemOnList": {
            "message": "Path `itemOnList` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `itemOnList` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "itemOnList"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "itemOnList"
        }
    },
    "_message": "bucketListItem validation failed",
    "message": "bucketListItem validation failed: status: Path `status` is required., itemOnList: Path `itemOnList` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
  }
}
```

Now, I have tried taking  'required: true' out of the model, and, I don't receive an error message anymore.

Instead , the route completely removes information from the database entry, and I receive something like this:

```
{       
 "completed": false,
 "_id": "5c8b05c701eb8007dceb3aaa",
 "__v": 0,
 "dateCreated": "null"
}
```

Here is the code for my route:

```
blRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function(req, res) {
BucketListItem.findById(req.params.id, function(err, 
bucketListItem) {
if (!bucketListItem) {
  res.status(404).send("Data not found.");
} else {
  bucketListItem.itemOnList = req.body.itemOnList;
  bucketListItem.status = req.body.status;
  bucketListItem.dateCreated = req.body.dateCreated;
  bucketListItem.completed = req.body.completed;

  bucketListItem
    .save()
    .then(bucketListItem => {
      res.json("Updated.");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({ error: err });
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
});
});

app.use("/bucketList", blRoutes);
```

And I have been using Body Parser and CORS, in case any one reading this wonders about that:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I hope I haven't phrased this in an unclear way or left anything out. If I have, please let me know.

And thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

So I've refactored, (I hope that's the correct word), my route, and it looks like this now:

```
blRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function(req, res) {
BucketListItem.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true})
.then(bucketListItem => res.json(bucketListItem))
.catch(err => res.status(404).send(err));
});
```

(Where it says {upsert: true}, I've also tried {new: true}.

And I've refactored my model a little:

```
let bucketListItem = new Schema({
itemOnList: { type: String, required: true },
status: { type: String, required: true },
dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
completed: Boolean
});
```

All of the rest of my code remains the same.

What happens when I run this code is, the document I'm trying to change,

```
{
"dateCreated": null,
"_id": "5c8b05c701eb8007dceb3aaa",
"completed": false,
"itemOnList": "Visit Venice",
"status": "Bought tickets.",
"__v": 0
}
```

comes back exactly the same. Nothing will have changed. I'm trying to change it to:

```
    {
    "completed": true,
    "_id": "5c8b05c701eb8007dceb3aaa",
    "itemOnList": "Visit Venice",
    "status": "btdt.",
    "dateCreated": null,
    "__v": 0
    }
```

As far as I can tell, the code for my route is correct, but I'm sure there's something little I'm just not noticing.
Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Those are validation errors from mongoose, and most likely because the values in `req.body` of the POST are not valid or not even supplied. Your very first step is to inspect `req.body` and ensure it actually contains what you expect, since it likely does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply update the document with this query:-

```
BucketListItem.findOneAndUpdate(
 { _id: req.params.id },
 req.body,
 { new: true, upsert: true }
);
```

Also, you don't have to mention default as false for fields. Just mention the type as Boolean instead of passing an object with type.

```
let bucketListItem = new Schema({
itemOnList: { type: String, required: true },
status: { type: String, required: true },
dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
completed: Boolean
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the changes you suggested, and the error I mentioned before went away, but now I get and empty object as a response. I tried adding {new: true} and {upsert: true}, but those didn't seem to do anything. Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: Can you please update the code you are using now so I can look into it.

Comment: `blRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function(req, res) {
  BucketListItem.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body)
    .then(bucketListItem => req.json(bucketListItem))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).send(err));
});`

Comment: That's the new route I'm working with. Sorry if it looks sloppy here.

Comment: There is a typo here. It should be res.json(bucketListItem) instead of req.json. Is it like this in your code too? I don't see anything else wrong here. You said you have already tried passing upsert and new options right? Please update that code too.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo! It didn't fix my main problem, but it did help. I've updated the rest of my code. Thanks again for your help, and I'm sorry if I'm being a pest.

Comment: Your schema has a typo. You are calling Date.now() instead it should just be Date.now. Also returnNewDocument is not a valid option. Just pass new: true and you should be good to go. Check the updated answer. And upsert true option will create a new document if no document already exists with the id you are checking. So if this is what you want then only include upsert true otherwise just pass new to true.